# InvalidRegex: Pattern value '(?:Y|N)' is not a valid regular expression.

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xsd2code

I have used regular expression for yes no type. but compiler throwing exception like this.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="YesNoType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Type for yes and no inputs.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="(?:Y|N)"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

InvalidRegex: Pattern value '(?:Y|N)' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: I have added this in xsd regular expression validation.

Comment: Take a look at XSD part 2, or at any book on XML Schema, for a definition of what regular expressions it allows. You can't assume that all regular expression dialects are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace it with something simpler like

```
Y|N
```

Or

```
[YN]
```

Or the like.

Non-capturing parens are not implemented in all versions of regex.